# System.diagnostics.process.start -System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Tags: c#

This is my code block:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fullpath;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + strNewFilePath;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

I am running an exe file using the System.diagnostics.process and i am keep getting this error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The application has
>   failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

The machine i am running this on is x64.

Googled it for a couple of hours, not much info on this. Any ideas?

Comment: By googling it, this seems to be quite complicated problem since it has something to do with registry, machine, update/installation error, etc... Some more, we do not know from the code, what specific process causes the issue. Maybe you can google about your specific process and look at its registry...? Some solutions even say you better reinstall your VS.

Comment: I will try to look it up some more and update the question

Comment: what program are you trying to run?  Are you compiling for 64 bit?  have you tried it as a 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Which application are you trying to run? Is it a 32-bit or 64-bit app?
You can check the event viewer Application log to figure out more information about this error.
If it due to some VC runtime then you can install the appropriate x86/x64 VCredist package (2005/2008/2010/2013) and see if it works for the application that you are trying to launch.